# How to switch between <div> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```
 <select id="typeselect" name="value" onchange="OnChangeSelect()" >
        <option value="1">General</option><br />
        <option value="2">Featured</option><br />
    </select>

    <div id="formbody" class="col-md-12">
  <div style="display:none" id="featured-div" disabled>
   <?php get_template_part("publish_game_fe") ?>
  </div>
  <div  style="display:block" id="general-div">
   <?php get_template_part("publish_game_nr") ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

depending on the option selected in the dropdown menu I want to display either the "featured-div" or the "general-div"

I tried that using the following script

```
    function OnChangeSelect()
{
    var e=document.getElementById("typeselect");
    var val = e.value;  
          if(val==1){
        document.getElementById("general-div").style.display="block";
        // document.getElementById("general-div").style.zIndex = 2;
        document.getElementById("featured-div").style.display="none";
         //document.getElementById("featured-div").style.zIndex = 1;
      }
      else{
            document.getElementById("general-div").style.display="none";
        // document.getElementById("general-div").style.zIndex = 1;
          document.getElementById("featured-div").style.display="block";
         // document.getElementById("featured-div").style.zIndex = 2;
      }
}
```

the form look like this

[image]
[image]

when I click on the select image button of "general-div" it does nothing
but when I click on the select image button if "featured-div" it opens the explorer twice. if I do not include one of those form the other works totally fine. I guess that hiding the div using style.display only makes it invisible and featured-div still overlaps the general-div .. what is the correct method to get this done ?

Comment: (Side note: `disabled` is not a valid attribute for `div` elements.)

Comment: [That code works just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/2c75hmbx/) Please create an [mcve] **using Stack Snippets** (the `<>` toolbar button) to create a runnable example of the problem in the question without intermixing PHP tags (since this question is about client-side code, you should include representative HTML the *browser* sees, not the PHP code that generates it).

Comment: yeah :D thats why it didnt work.. anyways thank you. but can you help me with the actual problem ?

Comment: See comment above.

Answer (score 1):

*you can use **jQuery's** show(),hide() functions to acheive the desired output instead of display:block and display:none*

Comment: tried that , it didnt work .. same problem